# How to get a copy of the production server SQLite database?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have developed two projects with django before, but I was never responsible for the deployment of the application or the production server. Now I got a freelancer work to do, and I need to get a copy of the database. I tried to run on the production server:

```
manage.py dumpdata > out.json
```

but it says I dont have the SECRET_KEY set. In the settings.py the secret key is being loaded from the system variables, but when I run:

```
os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY')
```

Its doesn't, find nothing. I also tried to find the db.sqlite3, but didnt find it either.
Can I set the SECRET_KEY to make the dumpdata? This can somehow crash the application? There is a better alternative to get production server database?

Comment: *"Now I got a freelancer work to do, and I need to get a copy of the database"* - then you should ask whoever is actually responsible for the server and database. What you're doing is basically hacking.

Comment: Why do you need a copy of the database to do development? Is there a need for you to work directly with (a copy of) live data?

Comment: Are you sure the production system is using sqlite?

Comment: The people responsible for the server are the company that made the website. It is kinda hacking, and its nice to do it. I need a copy because I need data to validade the changes I am implementing. And yes, I the production does use SQLite

Comment: If you need the data, *"ask them for it"*. If they're not willing to give it to you, ask *yourself* whether you should be using it at all.